# How do I mute all sounds of my application?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, mute

I'm creating a quiz app just for learning, and I've got a problem.

In my `mainactivity` I have a media player. It plays music even going through other activities, and I have a <kbd>mute</kbd> button to stop the music. I also have a sound effect when I successfully hit the right answer (on a question which is in other activity). But I don't know how to mute this SFX along with the background music when I press the <kbd>mute</kbd> button. Any hints? ;)

If it has a way to mute my entire application will be so good. I found some ways to mute, but this way will mute the entire system. And it's

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);
```

Comment: you can mute your mediaplayer right ?.. try this mediaplayer.setvolume(0,0);

Answer (score 3):

If you want to mute only the running apps sound, then you better do this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1); //Use your mediaplayer instance instead of this. Also maintain a single instance of mediaplayer for the entire app.
    mp.start();
```

#### For Mute

```
mp.setvolume(0,0);
```

**& Unmute or full volume**

```
mp.setvolume(0,1);
```

Reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float, float)

Answer (score 2):

You can just use AudioManager.setStreamMute(). Feel free to use the code below.

```
//mute audio
AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);

//unmute audio
AudioManager amanager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It may be of help to you.

```
AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);    
manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, 0, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
```

Comment: I will test these Codes when I back home, but Android manager doesnt mute the entire system? Another question, its good to make a class only for sound control? If so, how do i do that?

Comment: yes this idea is good..for that try `AsyncPlayer` ..http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/media/java/android/media/AsyncPlayer.java.shtml