# Mute sound for a Xamarin.Android app

Tags: android, xamarin, audio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am building a xamarin android app using the [XamarinMediaManager](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager). The control for now contains a placeholder for the Mute functionality but it isn't implemented yet:

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.VolumeManager.Mute = true;
//this doesn't work, even on the develop branch
```

I am not sure how else i could implement that, I've tried implementing that using the way suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441473/how-do-i-mute-all-sounds-of-my-application?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but most of the code seems to be deprecated in xamarin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: well simply find the latest version of  it then

Comment: The latest version doesn't implement it yet

Comment: what do you mean by does not implement it yet

Comment: I mean that there is only a placeholder, you can interrogate the Mute property but there is no actual code added to the library to handle the actual Mute operation : https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/issues/181

Comment: So you trying to do it in Xamarin forms and u have problems because mute doesnt work if i am right

Comment: No, actually i am on Xamarin.Android, i am looking to implement that or at least find a way to mute the sound for the app, a code snippet to mute the sound for an app would be appreciated, i've tried doing it this way : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441473/how-do-i-mute-all-sounds-of-my-application?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa but couldn't get it to work

Comment: Which of these answers did you try to use

Comment: Most of them, the first answer uses a SetStreamMute which is now deprecated, and i can't get the other answers to work for the current app !

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353629/how-to-turn-off-all-sounds-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use approuce with `AudioManager.SetStreamVolume`

All you need is chose sound chanel and set it to 0.

```
var audioManager = (AudioManager)getContext.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
var mute = 0;
audioManager.SetStreamVolume(Stream.Music, mute, 0);
```

If you need to use prev sound value just save it with

`var musicOrigVol = audioManager.GetStreamVolume(Stream.Music)`

One more thing `getContext` returns my `MainActivit`